# ASP.NET grid in 2.0 having trouble with paging to retain value of check box on save button click

Tags: asp.net

this is my button click code which fills the grid view

```
protected void Btnok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            if (Page.IsValid)
            {
                int passoutYear = Convert.ToInt32(passout.SelectedValue);
                int courseList = Convert.ToInt32(course.SelectedValue);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                string sep = "";




                foreach (ListItem li in Branch.Items)
                {
                    if (li.Selected)
                    {
                        sb.Append(sep + li.Value);
                        sep = ",";
                    }
                }

                DataTable dt = placedStudentManager.GetPlacedStudentList(sb, passoutYear, courseList);
                if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count != 0)
                {
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                    GridView1.Visible = true;
                    Btnsave.Visible = true;
                    ViewState["dt"] = dt;
                }
                else 
                {
                    noRecordExistOnOkButton.Text = "No Record Exist To Be Inserted For Recruited Students";
                    Btnsave.Visible = false;
                    GridView1.Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            COMMON.logger.Error("Error On Button Btnok_Click:CompanySelected.aspx.cs ", ex);
        }
    }
```

this is my button save which save the checked check box gridRow in data base

```
 protected void Btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            if (Page.IsValid)
            {
                int passoutYear = Convert.ToInt32(passout.SelectedValue);
                int companyId = Convert.ToInt32(company.SelectedValue);
                int courseId = Convert.ToInt32(course.SelectedValue);
                string package = txtpackage.Text.Trim();
                string venu = txtvenue.Text.Trim();

                DateTimeFormatInfo dateInfo = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
                dateInfo.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
                DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(vistDate.Text.Trim(), dateInfo);

                DataTable gridviewTbl = new DataTable();
                DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("company_id");
                DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("course_id");
                DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("branch_id");
                DataColumn dc4 = new DataColumn("student_enrollment");
                DataColumn dc5 = new DataColumn("company_visit_date");
                DataColumn dc6 = new DataColumn("venu");
                DataColumn dc7 = new DataColumn("package");
                DataColumn dc8 = new DataColumn("passout_year");
                gridviewTbl.Columns.Add(dc1);
                gridviewTbl.Columns.Add(dc2);
                gridviewTbl.Columns.Add(dc3);
                gridviewTbl.Columns.Add(dc4);
                gridviewTbl.Columns.Add(dc5);
                gridviewTbl.Columns.Add(dc6);
                gridviewTbl.Columns.Add(dc7);
                gridviewTbl.Columns.Add(dc8);

                if (GridView1 != null && GridView1.Rows.Count != 0)
                {
                    int rowCount = GridView1.Rows.Count;
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
                    {

                        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("Chek");

                        if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
                        {
                            string enrollmetNo = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text.ToString();
                            int branchId = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[0].Value);
                            gridviewTbl.Rows.Add(companyId, courseId, branchId, enrollmetNo, date, venu, package, passoutYear);
                        }
                        i++;
                    }

                    if (gridviewTbl.Rows.Count != 0)
                    {
                        Boolean b = placedStudentManager.SaveSelectdStudent(gridviewTbl);
                        gridNotExist.Text = "Records Successfully inserted";
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        gridNotExist.Text = "Please check the record to be inserted";
                        Btnsave.Visible = true;
                        GridView1.Visible = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    gridNotExist.Text = "Please Select The Recruited Student, so click the ok button first ";
                }

            }
            else 
            {
                GridView1.Visible = true;
                Btnsave.Visible = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            COMMON.logger.Error("Error On Button Btnsave_Click:CompanySelected.aspx.cs ", ex);
        }

    }
```

now  i am doing paging using following code

```
 protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {

        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        GridView1.DataSource = (DataTable)ViewState["dt"];
        GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView1.Visible = true;
        Btnsave.Visible = true;
       // StringBuilder str=(StringBuilder)ViewState["chk"];
        //foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows) 
        //{ 

        //}

    }
```

following is the grid view

```
   <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master Pages/AdminMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="CompanySelected.aspx.cs" Inherits="Admin_CompanySelected"  Trace="false"  Title="Untitled Page"  EnableEventValidation="false" %>


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cph1" runat="Server">

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function BranchCheckBoxCheck(source, args)
    {
      var chkBoxListId=document.getElementById ('<%=Branch.ClientID%>');
      var chkList=chkBoxListId.getElementsByTagName("input");
      for(var i=0;i<chkList.length;i++)
                {  
                    if(chkList[i].checked)
                    {
                        args.IsValid = true;
                        return;
                    }
                }
              args.IsValid = false;
    }
</script>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphMain" runat="Server">
    <div border="1">
        <table id="TABLE1" onclick="return TABLE1_onclick()" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td style="height: 24px">
                    Passout Year*</td>
                <td style="height: 24px">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="passout" runat="server">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:CustomValidator ID="validateYearForSaveButton" runat="server" ControlToValidate="passout"
                        ErrorMessage="insert passout year" OnServerValidate="validateYearForSaveButton_ServerValidate"
                        ValidationGroup="save"></asp:CustomValidator></td>
                <td style="height: 24px">
                <asp:CustomValidator ID="passoutYearRequire" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Passout Year is Compulsory" ControlToValidate="passout" ValidationGroup="verify" OnServerValidate="passoutYearRequire_ServerValidate">
                </asp:CustomValidator>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 101px; height: 24px;">
                </td>
                <td style="width: 126px; height: 24px">
                </td>
                <td style="height: 24px">
                </td>
                <td style="height: 24px">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Company Name*</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="company" runat="server">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;<asp:CustomValidator ID="selectComapnyForSaveButton" runat="server" ControlToValidate="company"
                        ErrorMessage="Select A Company" OnServerValidate="selectComapnyForSaveButton_ServerValidate"
                        ValidationGroup="save"></asp:CustomValidator></td>
                <td style="width: 101px">
                    Package*</td>
                <td style="width: 126px">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtpackage" runat="server" Width="197px"></asp:TextBox></td>

                <td>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtpackage" ValidationGroup="save" ID="packageRequire" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Package Require"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="Btnok" runat="server" Text="Ok" Width="43px" OnClick="Btnok_Click" ValidationGroup="verify" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Course*</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:UpdatePanel id="update" runat="server">
                        <contenttemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="course" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="course_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                         </contenttemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel><asp:CustomValidator ID="coursenecessaryForSaveButton" runat="server"
                        ControlToValidate="course" ErrorMessage="Select A Course" OnServerValidate="coursenecessaryForSaveButton_ServerValidate"
                        ValidationGroup="save"></asp:CustomValidator></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:CustomValidator ID="courseNecessary" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Select A Course"
                        OnServerValidate="courseNecessary_ServerValidate" ValidationGroup="verify"></asp:CustomValidator></td>
                <td style="width: 101px">
                    Branch Name*</td>
                <td style="width: 126px">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel id="upchak" runat="server">
                        <contenttemplate>
<asp:CheckBoxList id="Branch" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Branch_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    </asp:CheckBoxList> 
</contenttemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </td>
                <td>
                <asp:CustomValidator id="branchRequire" runat="server" ValidationGroup="verify" ClientValidationFunction="BranchCheckBoxCheck" ErrorMessage="Select A Branch"></asp:CustomValidator>
               <asp:CustomValidator id="branchrequireForSaveButton" runat="server" ValidationGroup="save" ClientValidationFunction="BranchCheckBoxCheck" ErrorMessage="Select A Branch"></asp:CustomValidator>
              <%-- <asp:CustomValidator ID="branchNotexist" runat="server" ErrorMessage="No Branch Exist" ValidationGroup="verify"  ControlToValidate="Branch" OnServerValidate="branchNotexist_ServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>--%>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ValidationGroup="save" ID="Btnsave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="Btnsave_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Company Visit Date*</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="vistDate" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="dateForSaveButton" runat="server" ControlToValidate="vistDate"
                        ErrorMessage="Visit Date Require" ValidationGroup="save"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
                <td style="width: 101px">
                </td>
                <td style="width: 126px">
                    <asp:Label ID="noRecordExistOnOkButton" runat="server" Text="Label" Width="178px"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Venue*
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtvenue"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td colspan="4">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="venRequire" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtvenue"
                        ErrorMessage="Insert venu" ValidationGroup="save" Width="73px"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                    <asp:Label ID="gridNotExist" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" Width="439px"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5" style="height: 16px">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">



<asp:GridView id="GridView1" AllowSorting="true" EnableViewState="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" AllowPaging="True"  DataKeyNames="branch_id, default_check, student_id"   OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="2">

<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select Student">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox id="Chek"  runat="server" Text="select" ></asp:CheckBox>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Enrollment No." DataField="enrollment_no" />
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Course Name" DataField="course_name"/>
<asp:BoundField  HeaderText="Branch Name"  DataField="branch_name"/>
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Email Id" DataField="email" />
<asp:BoundField  HeaderText="Mobile" DataField="mobile"/>
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name"  DataField="first_name"/>
<asp:BoundField  HeaderText="Surname" DataField="last_name" />
</Columns>


</asp:GridView> 
                </td>
            </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
  </td>
  </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
</asp:Content>
```

now i want to do paging without loosing check box state and want to save the selectd check box row in data base on save button click how to achieve this please let me know .
I am using dot net framework 2.0...

@PhilPursglove :- My solution is like this

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e) 
{ Response.Write(GridView1.PageIndex.ToString()); 
int d = GridView1.PageCount; bool[] values = new bool[GridView1.PageSize];
 CheckBox chb; 
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++) 
{ 
chb = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("Chek"); 
if (chb != null) 
{
 values[i] = chb.Checked; 
} 
}
Session["page" + GridView1.PageIndex] = values;
GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex; 
GridView1.DataSource = (DataTable)ViewState["dt"]; 
GridView1.DataBind(); GridView1.Visible = true; Btnsave.Visible = true; 
} 

protected void GridView1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
if (Session["page" + GridView1.PageIndex] != null) 
{ CheckBox chb; bool[] values = (bool[])Session["page" + GridView1.PageIndex]; 
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++) 
{ chb = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("Chek"); 
chb.Checked = values[i]; 
}
 }
 }
```

now i want on save button to store those selected chkbox row values to database

Comment: is there any body to help me out this

Comment: y people dont reslve my problem?
if there any difficulty in understaning question or poor formating make it unclear let me know all nagging issues so that i can correct those issues. But please have a glance to the above question

Comment: i want a perfect solution for this, if question is unclear please let me know i'll put more details in it. 
But let me know the best solution please. i am in dire need to  solve this question

Comment: Can you add the markup for the rest of your page i.e. what's on the page other than the gridview

Comment: i have put complete mark up now see above in the edited code

Comment: even if you want i can put complete aspx.cs page as well so that you can suggest me the code quality as well and may some other option by performance wise

Answer (score 2):

First of all, let me restate the problem as I understand it. You have a paged Gridview that has checkboxes on it. You select some of the checkboxes, then move to a different page. When you come back to the original page, you want those checkboxes to still be checked.

There are two elements to doing this, saving the CheckBox state on the old page, and then setting the Checkbox state on the new page.

Saving the CheckBox state on the old page

For every row in the gridview, we need to examine the checkbox to see if it's checked. If it is checked, we record the data id (from `DataKeys`) into a List. If it isn't checked but it was previously, we remove that id from the list. After we've done this for every row, we save the list in Viewstate.

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    List<int> selectedList;

    selectedList = (List<int>)this.ViewState["selectedList"];
    if (selectedList == null)
    {
        selectedList = new List<int>();
    }

    foreach (GridViewRow row in Gridview1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            CheckBox rowCheckBox;
            int rowId;

            // Get the Id
            rowId = (int)Gridview1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value;

            // Get the CheckBox
            rowCheckBox = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("Chek");

            if (rowCheckBox.Checked)
            {
                // Don't add the id if it's already in the list
                if (selectedList.Contains(rowId))
                { }
                else
                {
                    selectedList.Add(rowId);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Remove the id if it was there but now we've unchecked the box
                if (selectedList.Contains(rowId))
                {
                    selectedList.Remove(rowId);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Save the list into viewstate
    this.ViewState["selectedList"] = selectedList;

    // Do the paging as normal
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridView1.DataSource = (DataTable)ViewState["dt"];
    GridView1.DataBind();
    GridView1.Visible = true;
    Btnsave.Visible = true;
}
```

Setting the CheckBox state on the new page

Now we're in a new page, as we databind each row we need to examine whether the Checkbox needs to be checked. To do this we will get the list out of Viewstate and as we bind each row we look to see if the key for the row is present in the list - if it is, we check the Checkbox. First off we need to attach this method to the Gridview:

```
<asp:GridView id="GridView1"  OnRowDataBound="Gridview1_RowDataBound" 
...

protected void Gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    List<int> selectedList;
    int rowId;
    CheckBox rowCheckBox;

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        selectedList = (List<int>)this.ViewState["selectedList"];

        if (selectedList == null)
        { }
        else
        {
            rowCheckBox = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("Chek");

            // Get the id for the row
            rowId = (int)Gridview1.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value;

            // If the row Id is in the list then check the CheckBox
            if (selectedList.Contains(rowId))
            {
                rowCheckBox.Checked = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You should now be able to move between pages and your checkboxes will be persistent :-)

At the point where you click your Save button, I would guess that you want to remove the List from Viewstate (`this.ViewState.Remove("selectedList")`) so that you reset everything. The only other thing that youneed to be aware of here is that my demo code here is based on using a single field in `DataKeyNames` for the Gridview whereas you're using three fields, so you'll probably want to pick just one field to use for the list - I suspect studentId will do what you want e.g.

```
rowId = (int)Gridview1.DataKeys(row.RowIndex).Values["studentId"];
```

When you click your Save button, you need to get the list out of viewstate again, add any checked rows into it from the current page, and then use that to generate your datatable to pass to your manager object.

```
protected void Btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<int> selectedList;

    selectedList = (List<int>)this.ViewState["selectedList"];
    if (selectedList == null)
    {
        selectedList = new List<int>();
    }

    foreach (GridViewRow row in Gridview1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            CheckBox rowCheckBox;
            int rowId;

            // Get the Id
            rowId = (int)Gridview1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value;

            // Get the CheckBox
            rowCheckBox = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("Chek");

            if (rowCheckBox.Checked)
            {
                // Don't add the id if it's already in the list
                if (selectedList.Contains(rowId))
                { }
                else
                {
                    selectedList.Add(rowId);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Remove the id if it was there but now we've unchecked the box
                if (selectedList.Contains(rowId))
                {
                    selectedList.Remove(rowId);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    int passoutYear = Convert.ToInt32(passout.SelectedValue);
    int companyId = Convert.ToInt32(company.SelectedValue);
    int courseId = Convert.ToInt32(course.SelectedValue);
    string package = txtpackage.Text.Trim();
    string venu = txtvenue.Text.Trim();

    DateTimeFormatInfo dateInfo = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
    dateInfo.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(vistDate.Text.Trim(), dateInfo);

    DataTable gridviewTbl = new DataTable();
    ...

    foreach (int id in selectedList)
    {
        DataRow newStudentRow;
        newStudentRow = gridviewTbl.NewRow;
        newStudentRow[0] = id;
        newStudentRow[1] = courseid;
        ...
        gridviewTbl.Rows.Add(newStudentRow);
    }

    if (gridviewTbl.Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        Boolean b = placedStudentManager.SaveSelectdStudent(gridviewTbl);
        if (b)
        {
            gridNotExist.Text = "Records Successfully inserted";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        gridNotExist.Text = "Please check the record to be inserted";
        Btnsave.Visible = true;
        GridView1.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response i was looking for this solution for long back. I appreciate you response. Well i have achieved the state for check box while paging in grid view. Your's way is also immaculate and worth praising. But sir i need one more help  in this now on save button on button click a want all those checked rows to be set in database how should i do that and my misery is that if i take checked rows in temp datatable and then some body revert back to previous page and unchecked the check box how will i reflect it t data table. Would you please enlighten me on this as well

Comment: Please rid me off from remaining predicament that of saving checked rows of grid-view to be inserted in to database 
i did it in this way have a glance but remaining it yet to do..

Comment: protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write(GridView1.PageIndex.ToString());
        int d = GridView1.PageCount;
        bool[] values = new bool[GridView1.PageSize];
        CheckBox chb;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            chb = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("Chek");
            if (chb != null)
            {
                values[i] = chb.Checked;
            }

        }

Comment: i dont know how to edit this :- remaing down side

 Session["page" + GridView1.PageIndex] = values;
        
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        GridView1.DataSource = (DataTable)ViewState["dt"];
        GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView1.Visible = true;
        Btnsave.Visible = true;
}

Comment: to be continued:-
 protected void GridView1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
        if (Session["page" + GridView1.PageIndex] != null)
            {
                CheckBox chb;
                bool[] values = (bool[])Session["page" + GridView1.PageIndex];
                for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    chb = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("Chek");
                    chb.Checked = values[i];
                }
            }
    }

Comment: please edit this sir all above comment or please let me know how do edit this sort of comment ..............u nicely edited every thing.
if any key to be press fr this like CTR+D then please let me know

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet Can you edit your question and add all that code into the bottom of your question please.

Comment: @PhilPursglove:- I have added my solution to the above my existing asked question .....