# grid view databound event

Tags: asp.net

how data bound event of grid view is used and how is it called could somebody elaborate a bit on this please
i bind gridview on button click like this

```
DataTable dt = placedStudentManager.GetPlacedStudentList(sb, passoutYear, courseList);
                if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count != 0)
                {
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                    GridView1.Visible = true;
                    Btnsave.Visible = true;
                    ViewState["dt"] = dt;
                }
```

and whenever i need it again to bind i use view state like this, but can data bound event be any use instead of having view state can i use directly data bound event or some good alternate exist please let me know

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {

        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        GridView1.DataSource = (DataTable)ViewState["dt"];
        GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView1.Visible = true;
        Btnsave.Visible = true;
       // StringBuilder str=(StringBuilder)ViewState["chk"];
        //foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows) 
        //{ 


    //}

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `DataBound` event fires when all the databinding for the Gridview is finished, so that you could do, say, subtotals of all the rows in the Gridview at that point as you know there aren't going to be any more rows in the view. You call it like any other event, set the attribute in your markup and put the code in your code-behind:

```
<asp:gridview id="Gridview1" runat="server" ondatabound="Gridview1_DataBound" 
...
</asp:gridview>

private void Gridview1_DataBound(EventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

Could you use it in what you're doing? Possibly - can you put a bit more detail in your question about the way you're thinking?

Comment: can u give a glance to below link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598401/asp-net-grid-in-2-0-aving-trouble-with-paging-to-retain-value-of-check-box-on-sav

Comment: You might need to use the event "OnDataBinding" in the GV control, not "ondatabound" as shown above.