# Gridview autogeneratecolumns if column have rows

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, gridview

i have created a dropdownlist controler and gridview controler.

The gridview populate(shows) depending on what value the dropdownlist this is no problem.

In my sql table i have 3 columns that is in the gridview and what i would like to do is that in the gridview ONLY shows the columns that contain any row data.

Ex:

i choose in the dropdownlist value 1 then Kolumn 1,3 will show because those contain row data and colum 2 is NULL.

i choose in the dropdownlist value 2 then column 2 will show because that contains row data and the column 1,3 is null

in my dropdownlist ha have code-behind to poulate the dropdown list

and in the gridview i have aspx code.

Updated with Code:
This is my ASPX code.

```
<asp:GridView ID="FinanceGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass = "FinanceGridView" 
    DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="AdminPortal_ReportScheduling" 
    AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" Visible="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Report" HeaderText="Report" 
            SortExpression="Report" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Business_Area" HeaderText="Business_Area" 
            SortExpression="Business_Area" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Salesdepartment" HeaderText="Salesdepartment" 
            SortExpression="Salesdepartment" />
        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" 
            ShowEditButton="True">
        <ControlStyle BackColor="Black" ForeColor="White" />
        </asp:CommandField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

New Correct code?

```
Dim SqlConnectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Test").ConnectionString
Protected Sub BindDataToGridView()
    Using SqlConnection As New SqlConnection(SqlConnectionString)
        SqlConnection.Open()
        Dim SqlCommand As New SqlCommand("Select ID,Report,[Business Area],[Salesdepartment] from dbo.test", SqlConnection)
        Dim SqlDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(SqlCommand)
        Dim dataSet As New DataSet()
        SqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet)
        For Each col As DataControlField In Gridview1.Columns
            col.Visible = False
        Next
        For Each row As GridViewRow In Gridview1.Rows
            For i As Integer = 0 To row.Cells.Count - 1
                If row.Cells(i).Text.Replace("&nbsp;", String.Empty) <> String.Empty Then
                    Gridview1.Columns(i).Visible = True
                End If
            Next
        Next
        SqlConnection.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you created your own columns and got rid of AutoGenerateColumns, you could do it like this:

```
Protected Sub gvData_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    For Each col As DataControlField in gvData.Columns
        col.Visible = false
    Next
    For Each row as GridViewRow in gvData.Rows
        For i As Integer = 0 to row.Cells.Count - 1
            If row.Cells(i).Text.Replace("&nbsp;", string.Empty) <> string.Empty Then
                gvData.Columns(i).Visible = True
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

With autogenerated columns, this should work:

```
Protected Sub gvData_DataBound(sender as Object sender, e As EventArgs)
    Dim cols As New List(Of Boolean)
    For Each row As GridViewRow in gvData.Rows
        For i as Integer = 0 to row.Cells.Count - 1
            If cols.Count <= i
                cols.Add(False)
            End If
            If row.Cells(i).Text.Replace("&nbsp;", string.Empty) <> string.Empty Then
                cols(i) = True
            End If
        Next
    Next
    For i as Integer = 0 to gvData.HeaderRow.Cells.Count - 1 
        gvData.HeaderRow.Cells(i).Visible = cols(i)
    Next
    For Each row As GridViewRow in gvData.Rows
        For i As Integer = 0 to row.Cells.Count - 1
            row.Cells(i).Visible = cols(i)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

All this works only for fields displaying text (not for boolean fields displayed as checkboxes). I hope that my translation to VB is OK.

Comment: Hi and thank you but i don´t get this.
Where do i put my connection to my database? and where do i tell which columns i want to add?. 

Lets say a have 3 columns "Name","Birth","City" .

i do not use autogenerate filed

Comment: You can find answers to your questions here: http://www.vkinfotek.com/gridview/gridview-autogeneratecolumns-property.html.

Comment: i can not find what im asking for in the link you sent me?.

Comment: The link tells you how to connect to a database and how to define the columns without AutoGenerateColumns. All the defined columns should show up in the grid. To filter them according to your original question, use the first code example that I suggest in the answer, linking the procedure to the DataBound event of the GridView.

Comment: I know how to populate the gridview with data and connection it to a datasource controler so this is no problem. I then do NOT check "autogenerate filed" and i can then choose what column i want to show. The thing is that i would like to show field depending if there is data on a row or not. In you ex where should i put that? In the aspx.vb i think but should that do it? .... I will change "gvData" to my gridview name but should i change anything els?

Comment: The code given above goes in the VB file, yes. You can link the procedure to the DataBound event of the grid like this: <asp:GridView... OnDataBound="gvData_DataBound">. You can see another example in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598574/grid-view-databound-event.

Comment: You can see my answer given four minutes ago. By the way, maybe you could also update the title of the topic. "autogeneratecolumns" in the title is misleading (at least for me).

Comment: Hi, please have a look at my edit code. is this the way i should do it?.
Im new at asp.net so that is why i might ask things twice

Comment: Hi Nils, sorry for the delay. I will be available only tonight (Eastern Canada time).

Comment: Hi thank you. Are you able to look at my code? And tell me what im doing wrong.  The gridview did not display at all when i put in the code (^)

Comment: Your GridView has the attribute Visible="False". You should remove that first. :-)

Comment: It only have that until i press a button that makes it visible=true so that is no problem.

Comment: OK. If your GridView is visible when the OnDataBound is not set, then you will have to see in the debugger what is going wrong inside of gvData_DataBound when OnDataBound is set.

Comment: Ok so everything looks OK in my "new code" ? And that should work ?

Comment: The only thing that I can say for sure is that I tested the code in my answer and it worked. As for the reason why your grid does not show up, tough for me to say.

Comment: Dont i have to bind the gridview in your code? I use a datasource control to bind everything

Comment: In my test, I did the data binding in the code. And I don't use paging. I don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: Hi, have a look at my "new code" i have updated that. im not getting this to work because i don´t know where you put your d atasource and how you bind your gridview. 
i have not put you method in <ASP:......> i have done everything in aspx.vb code behind. 
Can you please provide me with the code for your aspx and your aspx.vb if im doing this the wrong way?